# How to allow FTP on Google Compute Engine Windows VM?

Tags: windows, ftp, sftp, google-compute-engine

All of the Google Cloud Platform instructions seem to be about setting up FTP in other OS like debian, etc.  Connection just times out.

On the Windows 2012 Server, I have setup FTP in IIS properly, but the firewall will not let me connect from the outside with FileZilla.

These Google Cloud Network firewall rules are already in place.

**Name    Source tag / IP range   Allowed protocols / ports   Target tags**

allow-ftp    0.0.0.0/0   tcp:21  ftp-server

allow-passive-ftp    0.0.0.0/0   tcp:5000-6000   Apply to all targets

allow-passive2-ftp   0.0.0.0/0   udp:5000-6000   Apply to all targets

I also made an inbound rule for ftp on port 21 in Windows Firewall.

Still cannot connect.  What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly is FTP failing?  Could you provide logs from your FTP client showing the commands/responses, and the error message?

Comment: If anyone is experiencing this issue, I'd like to say that this issue was discussed in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/dnNQwdfMBUw) and resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing exact same issue. Here's how I resolved this:

Inside the Windows VM, go to Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Inbound Rules 
Create New Rule to allow TCP port 21 connections.

There is already a default rule to allow FTP Traffic In on Port 21 but it has some attached restrictions related to NAT.

After adding a manual rule as above, FTP access from FileZilla starting working instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Windows instance in GCP you should allow the FTP traffic in your internal firewall ( the firewall from the instance ) and the firewall of you GCP project.

Also it could be caused by the passive mode. View this article : [Failed to retrieve directory listing filezilla connecting to IIS FTP behind NAT »  Grant Curell](http://grantcurell.com/2013/12/31/failed-to-retrieve-directory-listing-filezilla-connecting-to-iis-behind-nat/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, other answers do not work, but when I change the range of the firewall rules everything starts to works fine. I have created only tcp rule:

allow-passive-ftp 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:49152-65535 Apply to all targets.

My FTP site has the following firewall options:

[IIS FTP Firewall Support configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3n08.png)