# Enabling FTP Access on Google Cloud Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, ftp, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

This should be simple but can't seem to get it to work.

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance running on Google Compute and want to enable FTP access.

The FTP service is up and running and I can connect to it locally via the command line but cannot externally (times out). Firewall rule looks OK to me. Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: One thing to check is that the FTP server is binded to all the IP addresses and not only to localhost.  You can do that using “netstat -an” as discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/dnNQwdfMBUw). Have you defined tags in the firewall rules? If so make sure the instance has the appropriate tag as explained in the same discussion.  Also be aware that if you are using [passive ftp](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) you might need to open other ports.

Comment: Forgot to mention to also check the [Windows Firewall](https://serverfault.com/questions/762745/how-to-allow-ftp-on-google-compute-engine-windows-vm). There is a nice troubleshooting section [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/dnNQwdfMBUw). If you were able to solve this issue please consider posting an answer it would benefit the rest of the community.